# ¿Cómo limito la longitud de una propiedad string de una clase?

Tags: c#

Tengo una estructura de datos que estoy tratando de representar por medio de unas clases (windows forms), pero tengo la inquietud en saber si puedo restringir la longitud de las cadenas que van a ingresar.

Ahora, una clase ejemplo como lo estoy representando sería la siguiente:

```
public class RipsAF
{
    public string CodigoPrestador { get; set; }
    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }
    public string TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumeIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumFactura { get; set; }
}
```

Pero, por ejemplo, quiero restringir la propiedad `CodigoPrestador` donde no soporte cadenas de más de 10 carácteres.

Comment: La verdad no conozco la respuesta, pero, yo opino que la longitud del string debería ser validada _entre otras cosas_ por la lógica del programa; la clase es la representación de un objeto. Sin embargo, te comparto este [enlace de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.stringvalidatorattribute.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) que tal vez te pueda ser de ayuda. - ten en cuenta la versión del Framework que estás usando.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco mas cómo piensas usar esta estructura, el comportamiento deseado cuando la cadena es demasiada larga, o si estás usando un framework en particular? Porque no existe un tipo en el [sistema de tipos comunes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx) de .NET que automáticamente te permita definir esa clase de restricción con las cadenas. Todo lo tendrías que hacer manualmente, como lo puedes ver en la respuesta que has recibido. Pero si estás usando un framework en particular, puede que existan herramientas que puedas usar para lo que pides.

Comment: Es que resulta que debo cargar miles de registros a una estructura en una base de datos, ademas presentar un informe de los datos que no cumplen con la estructura. uso el .Net framework 4.5

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)? Es un framework .NET diseñado para trabajar con bases de datos y que te facilita definir esta clase de reglas.

Comment: hace un tiempo intente hacer una carga algo parecida de datos con Entity Framework y se demoro considerablemente mas que cuando lo importo con el motor de base de datos, por esta razón opte por generar los archivos y dejar la carga al motor

Comment: En efecto, bajo ciertas circunstancias, EF tiene ciertos problemas de rendimiento. ¿Pudieras aclarar un poco mas el comportamiento deseado? ¿Deseas que la estructura pueda aceptar la cadena muy larga pero que puedas identificar cuales se pasaron de longitud? ¿Deseas que te lanze una excepción cuando tratas de asignarle una cadena demasiada larga? O, tal como en la respuesta de Elenasys, ¿quieres que la cadena se recorte automáticamente?

Comment: @sstan justo esto. Deseo que te lanze una excepción cuando trate de asignarle una cadena demasiada larga

Comment: @jeissoni22 estoy de acuerdo con el primer comentario de Mauricio, desgraciadamente en ocasiones nos toca batallar con datos que previamente se ingresaron mal: "Es que resulta que debo cargar miles de registros a una estructura en una base de datos, ademas presentar un informe de los datos que no cumplen con la estructura.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres implementar algo de lógica en las propiedades de tu clase, NO debes usar Propiedades Autoimplementadas. Debes definir un campo (field) y luego escribir tu propiedad. Después de ello en el setter establecer la lógica que requieras (en tu caso validar el tamaño) y lanzar una excepción o descartar el valor no válido. Te pongo únicamente el ejemplo en la propiedad `CodigoPrestador`

```
public class RipsAF
{
    private string _codigoPrestador;
    public string CodigoPrestador 
    { 
      get { return _codigoPrestador; }
      set
      { 
         if(value.Length > 10) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Código Prestador no válida");
         _codigoPrestador = value;
      }
    }
    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }
    public string TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumeIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumFactura { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Puedes incluso limitar en el setter el tamaño a almacenar haciendo un _codigoPrestador = value.Substring(0, 10);

Answer (score 3):

Puedes limitar la longitud de la propiedad de tu objeto mediante `Substring()` y definiendo la longitud máxima , este es un ejemplo:

```
private string _cadena;
private int MaxLength = 10;
public string Cadena
{
    get { 
      if (_cadena.Length > MaxLength)
    _cadena = _cadena.Substring(0, MaxLength);
      return _cadena; 
     }

    set { _cadena = value; }
}
```

---

Un ejemplo adecuado a tu código, por ejemplo si defines limitar la propiedad `NumFactura` a 10 caracteres ya sea en `get` :

```
 public class RipsAF
{

    private string _numfactura;
    private int MaxLength = 10;

    public string CodigoPrestador { get; set; }
    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }
    public string TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumeIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumFactura
    {
        get
        {
            if (_numfactura.Length > MaxLength)
                _numfactura = _numfactura.Substring(0, MaxLength);
            return _numfactura;
        }

        set { _numfactura = value; }
    }

}
```

o en `set` :

```
   public string NumFactura
        {
            get
            {               
                return _numfactura;
            }

            set {
                if (value.Length > MaxLength)
                    value = value.Substring(0, MaxLength);
                _numfactura = value; }
        }
```

Para comprobar instancias la clase, almacenas el valor y después lo obtienes limitado a 10 caracteres:

```
RipsAF c = new RipsAF();
c.NumFactura = "StackOverflow.com";            
Console.Write("valor de NumFactura : " + c.NumFactura);
```

Tendras un valor de salida:

```
valor de NumFactura : StackOverf
```

---

> podría retornar un mensaje de excepción y no el substring?

```
    public string NumFactura
    {
        get
        {               
            return _numfactura;
        }

        set {
            if (value.Length > MaxLength)                    
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de numero de factura no valida.");
            //value = value.Substring(0, MaxLength);
            _numfactura = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pedro Ávila y Elenasys muchas gracias por su ayuda. podría retornar un mensaje de excepción y no el substring?

Comment: @jeissoni22 claro que sí, agregue actualización.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque se puede hacer la validación de la forma propuesta en las otras respuestas, si tienes varias clases y varias propiedades en cada clase, se requiere mucho código repetido para verificar la longitud de cada cadena. Y eso rápidamente se vuelve muy tedioso.

Por ejemplo, si tomamos la clase `RipsAF` en tu pregunta:

```
public class RipsAF
{
    public string CodigoPrestador { get; set; }
    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }
    public string TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumeIdentificacion { get; set; }
    public string NumFactura { get; set; }
}
```

... y decidimos aplicar restricciones de longitud a cada cadena, el código resulta en algo mucho más verboso (basándome en la respuesta de @Sergio Parra, pero aplicando la validación a cada propiedad y ajustado para que no falle cuando el valor es `null`):

```
public class RipsAF
{
    private string _codigoPrestador;
    public string CodigoPrestador 
    { 
      get { return _codigoPrestador; }
      set
      { 
         if(value?.Length > 10) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Código Prestador no válida");
         _codigoPrestador = value;
      }
    }

    private string _nombreProveedor;
    public string NombreProveedor 
    { 
      get { return _nombreProveedor; }
      set
      { 
         if(value?.Length > 5) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Nombre Proveedor no válida");
         _nombreProveedor = value;
      }
    }

    private string _tipoIdentificacion;
    public string TipoIdentificacion 
    { 
      get { return _tipoIdentificacion; }
      set
      { 
         if(value?.Length > 50) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Tipo Identificacion no válida");
         _tipoIdentificacion = value;
      }
    }

    private string _numeIdentificacion;
    public string NumeIdentificacion 
    { 
      get { return _numeIdentificacion; }
      set
      { 
         if(value?.Length > 12) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Numero Identificacion no válida");
         _numeIdentificacion = value;
      }
    }

    private string _numFactura;
    public string NumFactura 
    { 
      get { return _numFactura; }
      set
      { 
         if(value?.Length > 8) throw new InvalidOperationException("Longitud de Numero factura no válida");
         _numFactura = value;
      }
    }
}
```

Tal vez sea solo mi opinión, pero no me gusta mucho el resultado.

**Solución alternativa: usando un dynamic proxy**

¿Qué tal si pudieramos extraer la lógica que verifica la longitud de las cadenas y centralizarla para evitar que la clase se contamine de código repetido? Pues esto se puede lograr usando *atributos* y *dynamic proxies*.

La idea básica es la siguiente:

- Para *definir* la longitud máxima de las diferentes propiedades, simplemente lo haces anotando la propiedad con un atributo.
- Para *aplicar* la restricción de longitud máxima, se necesita crear un *proxy* que trabaja igual como si tuvieras una instancia normal de tu clase, pero que de forma transparente intercepta las llamadas a las propiedades para poder validar las cadenas.

Varios frameworks populares usan esta técnica, a menudo sin que nos demos cuenta de cómo lo logran (ejemplo: Entity Framework).

Usando esta técnica, podemos expresar la clase `RipsAF` de esta manera mucho más sencilla y más clara:

```
// Requiere referencia a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class RipsAF
{
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public virtual string CodigoPrestador { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(5)]
    public virtual string NombreProveedor { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(12)]
    public virtual string NumeIdentificacion { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(8)]
    public virtual string NumFactura { get; set; }
}
```

Como se puede ver, solo es cuestión de agregar el atributo [`MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) a las propiedades que necesitan que se validen la longitud máxima.

El otro detalle, es que hay que marcar las propiedades con la palabra clave `virtual`. La razón es que, para validar las cadenas, el *proxy* necesita interceptar las llamadas a las propiedades. Y la forma como se logra esa intercepción es por medio de heredar de la clase en cuestión y modificando la implementación de las propiedades de forma automática. Pero esto solo se puede lograr con propiedades marcadas `virtual`.

Ahora bien, esa es la parte sencilla. La parte más complicada es la de escribir el código que crea el *dynamic proxy* y que intercepta las llamadas a las propiedades.

Pero como regalito, dejo aquí el código que maneja esa parte y que puede crear el *proxy* para cualquier clase. (No puedo explicar cada detalle de este código, porque mi respuesta ya se está extendiendo demasiado. Pero, para los que les interese, vale la pena examinar el código más de cerca.) Para que funcione el código, necesitas incluir la librería [*Castle.Core*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core) en tu proyecto que se puede encontrar gratis en *NuGet*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;

public static class EntityBuilder<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
    private static readonly InterceptorAndHook interceptorAndHook = new InterceptorAndHook();
    private static readonly ProxyGenerationOptions generationOptions = new ProxyGenerationOptions(interceptorAndHook);

    // Este es el método que hay que llamar para crear el proxy que se encargará de
    // interceptar las llamadas a las propiedades y de validar automáticamente la 
    // longitud de las cadenas.
    public static T Build()
        => proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy<T>(generationOptions, interceptorAndHook);

    private class InterceptorAndHook : IInterceptor, IProxyGenerationHook
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<MethodInfo, SetterMethodInfo> setterMethodInfoMap
            = new Dictionary<MethodInfo, SetterMethodInfo>();

        public InterceptorAndHook()
        {
            // Aquí determinamos cuales propiedades queremos interceptar.
            // En este caso, son las propiedades públicas "set" de tipo "String"
            // que están anotados con el atributo "MaxLength(n)".
            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                                                && p.GetSetMethod() != null
                                                && !p.GetIndexParameters().Any()
                                                && p.IsDefined(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute))))
            {
                this.setterMethodInfoMap.Add(
                    prop.SetMethod,
                    new SetterMethodInfo(prop, prop.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>().Length));
            }
        }

        public void MethodsInspected() { }

        public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
        {
            // Para que el proxy pueda interceptar las llamadas a las propiedades,
            // es necesario que estén marcadas "virtual".
            // Este método verifica que la palabra clave "virtual" está presente
            // en las propiedades que deseamos interceptar. De no ser así, lanza una excepción.
            SetterMethodInfo setterMethodInfo;
            if (this.setterMethodInfoMap.TryGetValue(memberInfo as MethodInfo, out setterMethodInfo))
            {
                throw new Exception($"A la propiedad \"{setterMethodInfo.PropertyInfo.Name}\" le falta la palabra clave \"virtual\".");
            }
        }

        // Como hay un pequeñito costo asociado a la intercepción de un método/propiedad,
        // este método se encarga de definir la lista precisa de las propiedades que deseamos interceptar.
        public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
            => this.setterMethodInfoMap.ContainsKey(methodInfo);

        // Cada vez que se ejecuta un property set que requiere validación de la cadena,
        // este método intercepta esa ejecución y se encarga de verificar la longitud de la cadena.
        // Si la longitud es mayor a lo que se especificó en el atributo "MaxLength",
        // lanza una excepción adecuada.
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            string stringValue = (string)invocation.GetArgumentValue(0);
            if (stringValue != null)
            {
                int maxLength = this.setterMethodInfoMap[invocation.Method].MaxLength;
                if (stringValue.Length > maxLength)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{invocation.TargetType.Name}.{invocation.Method.Name}: La cadena excede la longitud máxima de {maxLength}. Longitud actual: {stringValue.Length}.");
                }
            }

            invocation.Proceed();
        }

        private class SetterMethodInfo
        {
            public SetterMethodInfo(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, int maxLength)
            {
                this.PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
                this.MaxLength = maxLength;
            }

            public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }
            public int MaxLength { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez que tienes esta clase `EntityBuilder<T>` incluída en tu proyecto, usarla con la clase `RipsAF`, o cualquier otra clase, es sumamente fácil:

```
// Crea un proxy que funciona exactamente como si tuvieras una instancia normal de "RipsAF".
// Si tienes curiosidad, puedes ejecutar "Console.WriteLine(entity.GetType().FullName);
// para que veas que en realidad es una instancia de una clase "proxy" que hereda de "RipsAF".
RipsAF entity = EntityBuilder<RipsAF>.Build();

entity.CodigoPrestador = "1234567890"; // Funciona bien, está dentro de los límites.
entity.CodigoPrestador = "demasiado largo"; // muy largo. Lanza una excepción.
```

La segunda asignación a la propiedad `CodigoPrestador` resulta en la excepción siguiente:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: RipsAF.set_CodigoPrestador: La cadena excede la longitud máxima de 10. Longitud actual: 15.

**Notas finales**

Hay que reconocer la complejidad de escribir el código que crea el *dynamic proxy* que intercepta las propiedades de forma automática. La implementación de la clase `EntityBuilder<T>` es prueba de ello.

Pero usar esta técnica tiene ventajas interesantes:

- No hay necesidad de repetir el código que valida la longitud de las cadenas. Mas bien, esa lógica queda centralizada. De modo que para hacer un ajuste a la lógica de validación, solo hay que hacerlo en un lugar para que tome efecto en cualquier clase que lo use.
- Aplicar la validación a mas clases o propiedades es trivial.
- Las clases que deseas validar permenecen sencillas, compactas y fáciles de entender.
- Es relativamente sencillo de agregar otros tipos de validación si lo deseas.

Comment: Hola @sstan esta interesante el código que proporcionas lo voy a analizar, me parece que también se podría validar usando la libreria FluentValidation.

Comment: Hola @Pedro. Nunca había oído hablar de FluentValidation. Se ve muy interesante y el código se ve muy limpio. Gracias por mencionarlo. Lo voy a investigar mas.